# 400 bad request in curl command

Tags: linux, curl

I'm trying to upload one file (50 GB) to share point.

Here is my command

```
curl --ntlm --user user:password --upload-file /mydata/updatefile.dat -k -G https://mysharepoint/data/1/2/updatefile.dat --data-urlencode 'param1=shared documents' --data-urlencode 'param2=sales budget data files'
```

Its showing below error

```
HTTP/1.1 400 BAD REQUEST
```

I'm using `-data-urlencode` becasue when I open my sharepoint url in browser it has `%20` instead of spaces. But spaces are actually present in sharepoint directory names.

```
https://mysharepoint/data/shared%20documents/sales%20budget%20data%20files/
```

Can anyone suggest what am doing wrong in this command ?

Comment: [This thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/a3cc7c51-8451-42d8-bd4a-c8bf0438c026/need-to-upload-files-from-linux-to-sharepoint?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious) suggests a curl command line.

Comment: @larsks have seen that link..but in my case url has spaces where directory names are present. Like 'shared documents' and 'sales budget data files' . Curl is not working if am running it with %20 in url. SO looking for specific way to do it if any